# select value can not be accessible from aspx code behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I have to fetch the html select control value from the aspx code behind...I have done the following coding so far:

The following code snippet is the jquery to populate the dropdown:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {       // load jQuery 1.5
            function loadfail() {
                alert("Error: Failed to read file!");
            }

            function parse(document) {
                $(document).find("combo").each(function () {
                    var optionLabel = $(this).find('text').text();
                    var optionValue = $(this).find('value').text();
                    $('#combo1').append(
                   '<option value="' + optionValue + '">' + optionLabel + '</option>'
                    );
                });
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: 'dropdown.xml',    // name of file with our data
                dataType: 'xml',    // type of file we will be reading
                success: parse,     // name of function to call when done reading file
                error: loadfail     // name of function to call when failed to read
            });
        });

    </script>
```

The following code snippet is the html select declaration:

```
<select id="combo1" ></select>
```

Can anybody please help me how to get the selected value of the dropdown in aspx code behind.

Regards,

Comment: try adding runat="server"

Comment: have already tried it but once i put runat="server" the dropdownlist is not populating...its coming blank

Comment: You will anyway have very few control on this if you don't use the .net control instead of HTML control. That said, you might want to move the logic to server-side... why is it client-side for now while you could totally parse xml file server-side then render it ?

Comment: i did not find it handy to code it using asp.net dropdownlist with jquery so tried this client-side code...can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead I have used the following trick

in .aspx page I have used this

```
<select id="combo1" name="a">
```

in .aspx.cs page I have used this

```
string strValue = Page.Request.Form["a"].ToString();
```

This gives me the index no and rest sorting I will do...

Answer (score 1):

Your dropdown should be added runat=server

```
<select id="combo1" runat = "server"></select>
```

and your script need to be changed, because you changed html control to server control. so that your script will be like this,

```
function parse(document) {
                $(document).find($("#<%=combo1.ClientID %>")).each(function () {
                    var optionLabel = $(this).find('text').text();
                    var optionValue = $(this).find('value').text();
                    $('#').append(
                   '<option value="' + optionValue + '">' + optionLabel + '</option>'
                    );
                });
            }
```

Comment: yes now the dropdown is populating data and runat="server" is added... in the code behind I am using string strValue = combo1.Value.ToString(); but it fetching blank value.

Comment: It should be strValue = combo1.SelectedValue;

Comment: But its giving option of combo1.selectedindex no selectedvalue

Comment: If you want selected VALUE then combo1.SelectedValue else if you want selected TEXT, then it should be combo1.SelectedItem.Text

Comment: am really sorry to say but I have checked it now that the above code is not working...